# Android: How to use Path and PathMeasure propertly

Tags: android, path

I need to compare one `Path` Object with another. First I collect all drawn objects in one Path at `onTouchEvent`:

```
 switch (event.getAction())
 {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                path.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 20, Path.Direction.CW);
        ...
```

Then I tried to analyze the resulting `Path` object by dividing it with `PathMeasure`, but I couldn't .
It has `nextContour()` method, but when I use it, nothing happens: `getLength()` or `getPosTan()` returns same values.
Maybe I need to store each figure in separate `Path`? Or get those objects another way? Or is it possible to compare the whole `Path` objects with another without dividing them to independent contours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think it'll help you

```
PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(mPath, false);
int pathCont=0;
do{
  pathCont++;
  Log.i(" length of Path", String.valueOf(pm.getLength()));

 }while(pm.nextContour());
```